# Loose house rules questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

I see a lot of questions asking for generic house rules for a game.  I don't really think that fits.

I think questions about house rules to solve specific problems, or the benefits of a house rule are ok, but "what are your house rules" questions aren't real questions (this is also the stance on [RPG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)).

Should we allow these broad house rules questions?

Answer (score 6):

I agree.  House rules questions should be asking about solving a specific problem, not just "everybody list your house rules".

Answer (score 1):

I think they should be allowed as community questions, so there's one place someone could go to to learn about different variations for a specific game.

Comment: Is there a difference between "house rules" and "variants"?  I see house rules as being designed to tweak a small part of the original rules in order to solve an imbalance or problem.
I see variants as bigger changes for the sake of fun and variety.  I would support community wiki questions for variants, but not for house rules.

Comment: No, I disagree.  We're not here to keep lists (where's Grace Note when we need her).  Besides, [users can't make questions community wiki anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183).  We don't want to create a new perpetual task for the mods.

Comment: @lilserf, I don't think "house rules" are always created to solve a problem. I've known people to make up house rules just to make the game interesting, or because they wanted to...